# Combine async and sync function results properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I try to combine two function values (from `a()` and `b()`), but the code is not waiting on the await-statement in function `test` as expected. Instead the result value prints directly the wrong result.

```js
function resData(status, message) {
  return { ok: status, message: message };
}

function a() { 
  return resData(true, 'A'); 
}

async function b() {
  // simulate some long async task (e.g. db call) and then return the boolean result
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  }); }
  await sleep(2500);
  return resData(true, 'B');
}

async function isValid() {
  const promises = [a, b].map(async (fnc) => { return await fnc().ok; });
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  // combine the results to one boolean value
  return results.every(Boolean);
}

async function test() {
  // not waiting here
  const res = await isValid();
  // prints directly - wrong result false
  console.log('result', res);
}

test();
```

After the wrong result output it waits 2.5 seconds. I think it has to do with the function call of `resData`, but I couldn't figure it out by myself, where my async / await misunderstanding is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `await fnc().ok` -> `(await fnc()).ok` otherwise you're only awaiting `undefined` since `fnc()` returns a promise and `.ok` on that promise returns `undefined`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd say there is <strike>2</strike> 1 problem with your code

1. <strike>`a` was not returning a promise, so you cant treat it as one</strike> - ignore turns out you can, who knew!
2. You cant await a boolean, so `await fnc().ok` made no sense.

I would suggest you

1. <strike>Make `a` return a promise even if its just a resolved promise</strike>
2. Execute just the methods in the `map`
3. Read the value of `ok` within the `every` call to determine if all promises resolved with this value set to `true`

With these changes, it works how I suspect you expected with a 2.5 second wait before writing to the console.

```js
function resData(status, message) {
  return { ok: status, message: message };
}

function a() { 
  return resData(true, 'A'); 
}

async function b() {
  // simulate some long async task (e.g. db call) and then return the boolean result
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  }); }
  await sleep(2500);
  return resData(true, 'B');
}

async function isValid() {
  const promises = [a, b].map(fnc => fnc());
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  // combine the results to one boolean value
  return results.every(x => x.ok);
}

async function test() {
  // not waiting here
  const res = await isValid();
  // prints directly - wrong result false
  console.log('result', res);
}

test();
```

Comment: you can indeed `await` on normal (not only `Promise`) object

Comment: Not only you can `await` on anything, you can also use promise static methods like `Promise.all()` with anything too. Precisely because a promise can resolve to anything.

Comment: @Jamiec btw, as far as my browser shows, you still have "You cant await a boolean" in the answer.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you very much for your answer. Also thanks for the hints in the comment section. I have also no idea, where all these downvotes came from.

Comment: @Habebit dont worry about is. SO can be weird sometimes, there was nothing wrong with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of awaiting for the function to be resolved, You are awaiting on value return by function.

```
async function isValid() {
  const promises = [a, b].map(async (fnc) => {

    //return await fnc().ok;
    // You have to await first function then call `.ok` value
     return (await fnc()).ok;
  });
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  // combine the results to one boolean value
  return results.every(Boolean);
}
```

Just to simplify the problem, Please check the below code.

```
async function test() {
  return { ok: true };
}
async function main() {
  // trying to await on undefined.. test().ok == undefined
  console.log(await test().ok); // undefined
  // first await function.. then return ok
  console.log((await test()).ok); // true
}
main();
```

Answer (score -3):

Async functions implicitly return a promise that will ultimately be resolved to the final value returned when the function execution ends.

So, you just need to call your functions inside your `map` callback to collect the promises. The array of results will be an array of `resData` objects. So, you finally check for each `ok` property to match your requirements.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

function resData(status, message) {
  return {ok: status, message: message};
}

function a() { 
  return resData(true, 'A'); 
}

async function b() {
  await sleep(2500);
  return resData(true, 'B');
}

async function isValid() {
  const promises = [a, b].map((fnc) => fnc());
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  return results.every((result) => result.ok);
}

async function test() {
  const res = await isValid();
  console.log('result', res);
}

test();
```

Comment: I mean, pretty much a copy/paste of my answer without the minor faux pas but ok.

Comment: @Jamiec didn't see your answer until after I published mine. Code was 99% written by OP, so actually we both copied from him and it makes sense answers are similar (although we wrote different things). Finally, I didn't downvote anyone here, but if you ask me, you wrote many inaccurate things in your answer and you should be sure of things before confusing people.